# Hoisting in react components. How does it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hoisting

I want to understand how hoisting works with respect to react component. Please check https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hello-world-forked-mzbyn6?file=/src/index.js

I have included Test, Test2 and const hello variables to test hoisting.

According to function hoisting, (reference: [Function hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#function_hoisting)), Test function in example could be used before declaration.

But, Test2 is a function expression here, (reference: [function expression hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#function_and_class_expression_hoisting)), Test2 function should not be used before declaration. It should throw reference error. But, it doesn't throw in react component. why?

Also, hello is a const and should not be used before declaration.(Reference: [const hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#let_and_const_hoisting) It should also throw an error ideally. Why error is not thrown?

Note: My understanding could be completely wrong. Looking to understand the reasoning here.

Comment: The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Note: Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: `App()` is executed by `<App />`, inside `React.render(<App />, ...)`. By that time, `hello` has been declared. Why are you expecting an error?

Answer (score 2):

`Test`, `Test1` and also `hello` const are being used from inside `App`.

`App` doesn't get executed before their initialization, it just gets declared. By the time `App` is executed both functions and const are declared and initialized. That's why you don't get an error.

If you want to test the error for the const just put a `console.log(hello)` above the declaration, but outside of a function that will get called later.

Answer (score 1):

because the `App` component is just declared before initializing the `Test` and `Test1` components, it is called after initializing them.

I think this example can show you when you should expect a reference error

***Here You should expect an error***

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'test' before initialization

```js
 const main = () => {
  console.log("TEST", test())
}

// using main() function before initializing the test() function used inside it
main()

const test = () => {
  return "TEST Function"
}
```

***but here you will not get any error because use called `main()` function **after** declaring `test()` function***

> "TEST" "TEST Function"

```js
const main = () => {
  console.log("TEST", test())
}

const test = () => {
  return "TEST Function"
}

// using the function after initializing the test function used inside 
main()
```